# reading xaml file from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this situation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEIys.png

I have such a window, where the names of Topics are beiing generated from .xaml files, like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2XMP.png
the names of topics are being generated by this code

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Topic?.xaml");
        this.Topics = new List<Topic>();
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
        {
            var topic = new Topic();
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var page = (Page)XamlReader.Load(fs);
                topic.Page = page;
            }

            this.Topics.Add(topic);
        }
```

Now, I want when the appropriate Topic is clicked, for example Topic 2, the topic2.xaml is opening in new window, and if 3-rd is clicked the topic3.xaml is showing on new window.

Thanks guys for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do as shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx) using XamlReader

```
using(var mystr = File.Open(fileName))
     DependencyObject rootObject = XamlReader.Load(mystr) as DependencyObject;
```

However, this does not sound like a good pattern to me :/